# refresh custom list view after deleting through context menu

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

hi guys I'm very new to Android Development.I need your help,
I've been searching for hours but could not find a good enough solution. I've created a simple alarm app which has a Custom list view to display all the alarms that are available. i have added a context menu which on long click will enable users to delete the alarms. i was able to write the code to delete the alarm but i cant seem to be able to refresh the list View after it deletes(i tried this.recreate but that sucks)

I'm sure i have to use notifyDataSetChanged() but its not showing up as a method when i use myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() i've been searching for a solution for many days now and cant seem to find out

also note my db related method updateAlarm() addAlarm() and deleteAlarm() are in the DBHandler class (im not sure if they should be there or in the customAdapter class, after going through some of the other question threads in stackoverflow)

```
//MainActivity.java

private ListAdapter myCustomAdaptor; //global

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    myDbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this, null, null, 1);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Alarm alarm = alarmArray.get(info.position);
    int aid = alarm.getAlarmId();

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.delete) {

        alarmArray = myDbHandler.deleteAlarm(aid);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Alarm Deleted Successfully" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //NEED A WAY TO REPLACE THIS, BUT MUCH SMOOTHER :D
        MainActivity.this.recreate();


        return true;
    }if(item.getItemId()==R.id.edit){

        Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),AddNewAlarm.class);
        i.putExtra("alarmId",listId);
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here's the code for the customAdapter.java class(not used to implement delete)

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
Context myContext;
int myCustomLayoutId;
ArrayList<Alarm> alarmArray;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Alarm> alarms) {
    super(context, resource, alarms);

    this.myContext = context;
    this.myCustomLayoutId = resource;
    this.alarmArray = alarms;
}

@Override
public Alarm getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    PlaceHolder holder = null;

    //if we currently don't have anny row view to reuse..
    if(row==null){

        //inflate the layout for a single row
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(myContext);
        row = myInflater.inflate(myCustomLayoutId,parent,false);

        holder = new PlaceHolder();

        //get a reference to the different view elements we wish to update
        holder.listId =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtAlarmId);
        holder.listHour =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showHour);
        holder.listMin =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showMin);
        holder.listDayM =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayM);
        holder.listDayT =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayT);
        holder.listDayW =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayW);
        holder.listDayTh =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayTh);
        holder.listDayF =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayF);
        holder.listDayS =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDayS);
        holder.listDaySu =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showDaySu);
        holder.onOffAlarm =(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{

        holder = (PlaceHolder) row.getTag();

    }

    //get the data from the alarm array
    Alarm alarm = alarmArray.get(position);

    //Setup and reuse the same listener for each row
    holder.listId.setText(convertToDoubleDigits(alarm.getAlarmId()));
    holder.listHour.setText(convertToDoubleDigits(alarm.getHour()));
    holder.listMin.setText(convertToDoubleDigits(alarm.getMinute()));


    if(alarm.getDayM()){
        holder.listDayM.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDayT()){
        holder.listDayT.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDayW()){
        holder.listDayW.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDayTh()){
        holder.listDayTh.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDayF()){
        holder.listDayF.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDayS()){
        holder.listDayS.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getDaySu()){
        holder.listDaySu.setTextColor(0xff0098ff);
    }
    if(alarm.getStatus()){
        holder.onOffAlarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on);
    }else{
        holder.onOffAlarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_off);
    }

    //set on click listener on ImageView
    holder.onOffAlarm.setOnClickListener(ToggleListener);
    Integer rowPosition = position;
    holder.onOffAlarm.setTag(rowPosition);

    return row;
}

View.OnClickListener ToggleListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Integer viewPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Alarm alarm = alarmArray.get(viewPosition);
        DBHandler myDbHandler = new DBHandler(v.getContext(),null,null,1);

        updateResults(myDbHandler.toggleAlarm(alarm.getAlarmId()));
    }
};

public void updateResults(ArrayList<Alarm> results) {
    alarmArray = results;
    //Triggers the list update
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//Place holder to hold view references
private static class PlaceHolder{
    TextView listId;
    TextView listHour;
    TextView listMin ;
    TextView listDayM ;
    TextView listDayT;
    TextView listDayW ;
    TextView listDayTh ;
    TextView listDayF ;
    TextView listDayS ;
    TextView listDaySu;
    ImageView onOffAlarm ;
}

//Method to convert 12 hour time to 24 hort 1:1 to 01:01
private String convertToDoubleDigits(int i){
    if(i<10){
        return "0" +String.valueOf(i);
    }else{
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Custom ListView Class?

Comment: yup, i just updated the post with it, but i dont use it for the delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `updateResult()` and pass your ArrayList after deletion?

Use

```
yourAdapter. updateResults( results);
```

Comment: yup but it's not showing the 'updateResults' method when i call it via my adapter. i added my adapter as a global variable before onCreate() so that  my onContext.... can access it

Comment: Could somebody pleeeeeeeeeease help me! Ive got 3 days to finish this up and im stuck of this for days!! when i use myCustomAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged(); im my main activity the .notify.... part shows as red implying its not a method, also my updateResults() method is also not showing up?!! what am i doing wrong??? god please can someone help me!!!!